# Java: Is there a linear correlation between a font's point size and its rendered extent?

Tags: java, fonts, drawing, font-size, graphics2d

Let's say a string rendered with a **10-point font** is **200 pixels** wide. If I draw the same string with a **15-point font** (a 50% increase), will its rendered width also increase by 50% (to **300 pixels**)?

(Of course, this assumes no other changes in the font and the `Graphics2D` where the text is rendered.)

In other words, is there a direct linear relationship between a font's point size and the size text is rendered? Or are there other variables that prevent me from making any such assumptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close with your assumption.

However, the spacing between letters doesn't always scale exactly.  I believe it has to do with integer division sometimes having a remainder, but I haven't looked at the Java `FontMetrics` class code in a while.

You're safest always creating a new `Font` with the appropriate font size, and calling the `getStringBounds` method on the `FontMetrics` class.